# Unexpected characters returned when reading email using ImapX

Tags: c#, imap, imapx

When reading the body of an email using ImapX there is unexpected text at the end. A simplified version of the code is

```
using (var imapClient = new ImapClient(host, port, useSSL))
{
    if (!imapClient.Connect()) 
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Failed to connect to {0}:{1}", host, port));
    if (!imapClient.Login(username, password)) 
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Login failed for {0} connecting to {1}:{2}", username, host, port));
    imapClient.Folders.Inbox.Messages.Download();
    foreach (var message in imapClient.Folders.Inbox.Messages)
    {
        var body = message.Body.HasText ? message.Body.Text : message.Body.Html;
        //Other stuff
    }
    imapClient.Disconnect();
}
```

and when a test email was sent with body

> qwertyqwerqewrqwrqerwqreqrewrq

the body which was read using that code was

> qwertyqwerqewrqwrqerwqreqrewrq
>   )
>   IMAPX10 OK UID completed

Is there any way I can return the body text without the extra stuff at the end? The mail server sent the following

```
SENT: * OK IMAPrev1  
RECEIVED: IMAPX1 CAPABILITY  
SENT: * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 CHILDREN IDLE QUOTA SORT ACL NAMESPACE RIGHTS=texk[nl]IMAPX1 OK CAPABILITY completed  
RECEIVED: IMAPX2 LOGIN "the email address" ***  
SENT: IMAPX2 OK LOGIN completed  
RECEIVED: IMAPX3 LIST "" %  
SENT: * LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "INBOX"[nl]* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "Trash"[nl]IMAPX3 OK LIST completed  
RECEIVED: IMAPX4 EXAMINE "INBOX"  
SENT: * 1 EXISTS[nl]* 1 RECENT[nl]* FLAGS (\Deleted \Seen \Draft \Answered \Flagged)[nl]* OK [UIDVALIDITY 1453984022] current uidvalidity[nl]* OK [UIDNEXT 9] next uid[nl]* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS ()] limited[nl]IMAPX4 OK [READ-ONLY] EXAMINE completed  
RECEIVED: IMAPX5 EXAMINE "Trash"  
SENT: * 0 EXISTS[nl]* 0 RECENT[nl]* FLAGS (\Deleted \Seen \Draft \Answered \Flagged)[nl]* OK [UIDVALIDITY 1454000202] current uidvalidity[nl]* OK [UIDNEXT 1] next uid[nl]* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS ()] limited[nl]IMAPX5 OK [READ-ONLY] EXAMINE completed  
RECEIVED: IMAPX6 SELECT "INBOX"  
SENT: * 1 EXISTS[nl]* 1 RECENT[nl]* FLAGS (\Deleted \Seen \Draft \Answered \Flagged)[nl]* OK [UIDVALIDITY 1453984022] current uidvalidity[nl]* OK [UIDNEXT 9] next uid[nl]* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Deleted \Seen \Draft \Answered \Flagged)] limited[nl]IMAPX6 OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed  
RECEIVED: IMAPX7 EXAMINE "INBOX"  
SENT: * 1 EXISTS[nl]* 0 RECENT[nl]* FLAGS (\Deleted \Seen \Draft \Answered \Flagged)[nl]* OK [UIDVALIDITY 1453984022] current uidvalidity[nl]* OK [UIDNEXT 9] next uid[nl]* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS ()] limited[nl]IMAPX7 OK [READ-ONLY] EXAMINE completed  
RECEIVED: IMAPX8 UID SEARCH ALL  
SENT: * SEARCH 8  
SENT: IMAPX8 OK UID completed  
RECEIVED: IMAPX9 UID FETCH 8 (FLAGS INTERNALDATE RFC822.SIZE BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (FROM TO DATE SUBJECT CC CONTENT-TYPE)] BODYSTRUCTURE)  
SENT: * 1 FETCH (UID 8 RFC822.SIZE 2553 FLAGS (\Seen) INTERNALDATE "29-Jan-2016 14:47:58 +0000" BODYSTRUCTURE (("TEXT" "PLAIN" ("CHARSET" "UTF-8") NIL NIL "7bit" 6 2)("TEXT" "HTML" ("CHARSET" "UTF-8") NIL NIL "7bit" 27 2) "ALTERNATIVE" ("BOUNDARY" "001a113fefbe6b8657052a7a1da1") NIL NIL) BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (FROM TO DATE SUBJECT CC CONTENT-TYPE)] {235}  
SENT: )  
SENT: IMAPX9 OK UID completed  
RECEIVED: IMAPX10 UID FETCH 8 (BODY.PEEK[1.MIME] BODY.PEEK[1])  
SENT: * 1 FETCH (UID 8 BODY[1.MIME] {43}  
SENT:  BODY[1] {6}  
SENT: )  
SENT: IMAPX10 OK UID completed  
RECEIVED: IMAPX11 UID FETCH 8 (BODY.PEEK[2.MIME] BODY.PEEK[2])  
SENT: * 1 FETCH (UID 8 BODY[2.MIME] {42}  
SENT:  BODY[2] {27}  
SENT: )  
SENT: IMAPX11 OK UID completed  
RECEIVED: IMAPX12 SELECT "INBOX"  
SENT: * 1 EXISTS[nl]* 0 RECENT[nl]* FLAGS (\Deleted \Seen \Draft \Answered \Flagged)[nl]* OK [UIDVALIDITY 1453984022] current uidvalidity[nl]* OK [UIDNEXT 9] next uid[nl]* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Deleted \Seen \Draft \Answered \Flagged)] limited[nl]IMAPX12 OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed  
RECEIVED: IMAPX13 UID STORE 8 +FLAGS (\Seen \Deleted)  
SENT: * 1 FETCH (FLAGS (\Deleted \Seen) UID 8)  
SENT: IMAPX13 OK UID completed  
RECEIVED: IMAPX14 SELECT "INBOX"  
SENT: * 1 EXISTS[nl]* 0 RECENT[nl]* FLAGS (\Deleted \Seen \Draft \Answered \Flagged)[nl]* OK [UIDVALIDITY 1453984022] current uidvalidity[nl]* OK [UIDNEXT 9] next uid[nl]* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Deleted \Seen \Draft \Answered \Flagged)] limited[nl]IMAPX14 OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed  
RECEIVED: IMAPX15 EXPUNGE
```

Comment: It seems like there is a bug in your IMAP library. That extra text is simply part of the IMAP protocol; the library should take care of returning only the text of the message.

Comment: @legoscia it's almost certainly the case that there's a problem with the library, but it's very popular (Nuget states 18,402 downloads) and I haven't seen this issue elsewhere. Therefore, I suspect there's some setting in the code or on the mailserver which I can change to stop this happening. I'm hoping someone can shed some light on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have gone threw the same issue. After passing couple of hours I found that there was issue in regex pattern sequence.

Download the latest source from codeplex and just change the sequence describe below.

Go to the >>

> MessageContent.CS

& locate following code

```
else if (CommandEndRex.IsMatch(data))
            {
                for (var i = _contentBuilder.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    if (_contentBuilder[i] == ')')
                    {
                        _contentBuilder.Remove(i, _contentBuilder.Length - i);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
```

and keep up it one step above the previous else if statement and it's done.

Let me know if u still face the same issue..

happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Another, simpler approach is if you don't specially need anything which was changed/fixed/added since then, to downgrade to `ImapX` version `2.0.0.15`. Maybe some intermediate versions work too, but this works for sure.