# ImapX 2.0.0.18 - Unexpected characters in attachments base64 string

Tags: c#, base64, imap

This question is related to the following: [Unexpected characters returned when reading email using ImapX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35088734/unexpected-characters-returned-when-reading-email-using-imapx)

The solution here **doesn't work**.

The problem is that in some cases, the following string:

> ) IMAPX10 OK UID completed

is being added to the end of an attachment Base64 string. This causes the Base64 decoder throw an exception.

I tried fixing the

> MessageContent.cs

file like the above solution, but with no luck...

Does anyone came accross with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

ImapX is buggy and it's a serious bug. Fix it (it's open source after all) or use something else.

Fetch command processing involves returning x fetch items for each of y messages. One of those items is the base64 you want, and I assume y=1 in your case. The `)` you see indicates the end of the item list for a particular message, and the `OK...` indicates the end of the command processing for the command tagged `IMAPX10`. There's a byte count just before the base64 that describes the length of that item, a byte count that ImapX *really should not disregard*.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else running into this issue, I fixed it with the following:

```
Convert.FromBase64String(attachment.GetTextData());
```

This will give you the proper byte array, without the unnecessary bytes at the end of the file.